# Retrofit @Url use base url

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm facing weird problem with @Url annotation. I didn't found any solution or reason so far.

I'm using get method to download attachments.

```
@GET
Call<ResponseBody> getAttachment (@Url String url, @QueryMap Map<String, String> params);
```

But sometimes users get errors because retrofit try to use base url with @url. I noticed that in Fabric and I can not reproduce it myself so I can't know what is going on. Backend confirmed that app is trying to connect.
"/api" - stands for end of baseUrl and after that real url is placed.

```
GET /api/https://url_given_as_url_parameter
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem?